# How can I lower the maximum resolution on Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, resolution

Is there a way to lower the maximum resolution available in the display settings?  The highest one is higher than my monitor can support, and some programs default to the highest resolution available.  I normally use 1280x1024, but 1920x1080 is available.

I'm running Windows Vista with the GeForce GT 430 driver (the latest version, 295.73), and I've got a TV plugged into a VGA output on the video card as well.  The TV also can't support the higher resolution.

Comment: I don’t know about Nvidia, but for ATI cards, ATI Tray Tools lets you set/force limits. Perhaps [RivaTuner](http://www.guru3d.com/rivatuner/) can do that for Nvida cards.

Comment: Can you give an example of such a program so we can track down the programmers and administer appropriate corrective beatings?

Comment: It's portal 2, so it's very annoying that I can't run it!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Nvidia's control panel, there are alot more configurations you can alter via the control panel.

Here is a link to the Nvidia User Guide for this card: http://us.download.nvidia.com/Windows/295.73/295.73-NVIDIA-Control-Panel-Quick-Start-Guide.pdf

Comment: Yes, I've had a look there, but I can't see anything that helps.

Comment: Does it allow you to adjust the resolution with greater control over the general windows settings? When I had a Win machine I also had an nVidia card and in the control panel it gave me nearly twice as many different resolution settings.

Comment: I can adjust the resolution, but not the maximum resolution, which is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Not a proper solution, but I've got it to work.  Unplugging the analogue TV removed the offending option, and now everything works.  I suspect that Windows display settings didn't know exactly what the TV could display, guessed, and got it wrong.

If anyone comes across a way to inform Vista's guess, though, then please do share!